# Printing Linked List returns random symbols

Tags: c++, linked-list, adt, singly-linked-list

I have implemented a basic linked list in order to prepare for a more difficult one as an assignment. I can't seem to be able to print the contents of a node without printing out random symbols.
I know this means I am accessing bad memory but I cannot identify where or how it is happening.
Can someone please help me fix this error?

**built with g++ on linux**

Header File

```
#ifndef LLIST_H
#define LLIST_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
        int age;
        string name;
        string hair;
        int height;
        node* next;
};

node loadNode(node a, string b);


class linkedlist 
{
    private:
        node* head = NULL;
        node* tail = NULL;
        int size;
    public:
        linkedlist();
        linkedlist(node* n[], int si);
        int getSize();
        void print();
        void addNode(node add);
        void del(string record);
        node sort(node sortee);
        void printList();
        node * getHead();
};
#endif
```

Implementation

```
#include "list.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


node loadNode(node a, string b)
{
    int counter = 0;

    string ag = "";
    string nam = "";
    string hai = "";
    string hei = "";


    for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
    {
        if(b[i] == ',')
        {
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
        if(counter == 0)
            ag = ag + b[i];
        else if(counter == 1)
            nam = nam + b[i];
        else if(counter == 2)
            hai = hai + b[i];
        else
            hei = hei + b[i];
    }

    stringstream s(hei);
    stringstream o(ag);

    int f,g;
    s >> f;
    o >> g;

    a.hair = hai;
    a.height = f;
    a.age = g;
    a.name = nam;

    return a;

}

linkedlist::linkedlist()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    size = 0; 
}

linkedlist::linkedlist(node a[],int si)
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    size = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < si; i++)
    {
        addNode(a[i]);
    }

}

void linkedlist::addNode(node added)
{
    node * pointer = new node;
    //if the first element
    if(size == 0)
    {
        tail = pointer;
        pointer->next = NULL; 
    }
    pointer->next = head;
    head = pointer;

    //add data members 
    pointer-> age = added.age;
    pointer-> hair = added.hair;
    pointer-> name = added.name;
    pointer-> height = added.height;

    size++;

    //time to exit!
    pointer = NULL;
    delete pointer;
}

node *  linkedlist::getHead()
{
    node * temp = head;
    return temp;
}

void linkedlist::print()
{


    node* iterator = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    iterator = head;

    while(iterator != NULL)
    {
        printNode(iterator);
        iterator = (iterator->next);
    }
    iterator = NULL;
    delete iterator;
}

void printNode(node* printed)
{
    cout << printed->name << endl;
    cout << printed->age << endl;
    cout << printed->height << endl;
    cout << printed->hair<< endl;
}
```

main program

```
#include "list.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string k = "21,Ces Goose,brown,5";  
    string a = "25, SteveO, Brown, 6";
    string b = "23, Jimmy , Brown, 5";



    node d,f,c;
    d = loadNode(d,k);
    f = loadNode(f,a);
    c = loadNode(c,b);

    node lib[3] = {d,f,c};
    linkedlist doublel = linkedlist(lib, 3);

    doublel.print();



    return 0;


}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
6304000
@g���
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Time to fire up your program in the debugger, step through line by line, and check if all variable and pointer values appear as expected.

Comment: logic in `linkedlist::addNode` doesn't make any sense. you need to review it

Comment: @C.M. can you please be more specific, what part? or is it the order that I did the steps in

Comment: You are asking me to do your homework for you :-) Most of what you do in `addNode` doesn't make sense. Analyze it and figure out what is wrong

Comment: I ran exactly that and it worked! But i am not understanding how it is any different than before? all i did was change the order of assignments

Answer (score 0):

@C.M. please let me know if this fixes the issue

```
void linkedlist::addNode(node added)
{
    node * temp = new node;
    //add data members 
    temp-> age = added.age;
    temp-> hair = added.hair;
    temp-> name = added.name;
    temp-> height = added.height;

    //if the first element
    if(size == 0)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp->next = NULL; 
        size++;
    }
    else
    {       
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        size++;

        //time to exit!
        temp = NULL;
        delete pointer;
    }
}
```

also changed linkedlist doublel = linkedlist(lib, 3); to

```
linkedlist * doublel = new linkedlist(lib,3);
doublel->print();
```

in main() file